# Laravel 5 - sanitize certain inputs on validation

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Is it possible to sanitize certain inputs on (or before validation)?

I have this rules for now (as example):

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name'        => 'required|min:3|max:255|string',
            'description' => 'string',
            'hours.*'     => ['required', new Hours],
        ];
    }
```

I want to sanitize **name** and **description**, but I don't to sanitize **hours**. Is this possible to do on validation, or I have to sanitize after validation and before insert?

Comment: You can't change inputs during validation, what you can do is using a `FormRequest` object and call a sanitize method on it (which will return your sanitized inputs)

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend to do sanitization after validation.

Suppose we have a blog system and guests/users can comment on posts, and the minimum characters in a comment is `10`

If someone comments with `thank you`  (there's a trailing space), it will be passed at the validation level because it's a `10` chars comment, but when we sanitize the comment, say we trim it, it will be left with `9` chars. This is a silly example but can be something very important in your business logic somewhere.

**Sanitize then validate.**

To do request inputs sanitization, this article has a good pattern to do it https://medium.com/@melihovv/how-to-sanitize-input-data-in-declarative-manner-in-laravel-e4486068f751

Answer (score 0):

To cannot do this before validation as the original value will still be there in **request**. It can be easily dealt with mutators.

You can use Eloquent's **Mutators** to format attribute values in Eloquent Model before **insert** or **update**.

To define mutator, add **set** prefix and **attribute** suffix with the attribute's name. Like following

```
// Name mutator
public function setNameAttribute($name)
{
    $this->attributes['name'] = strtolower($name); // used strtolower just to show the mutation
}

// Description mutator
public function setDescriptinAttribute($description)
{
    $this->attributes['description'] = strtolower($description); // used strtolower just to show the mutation
}
```

Check documentation for more info https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could think of validating the input like that would be validating it on the client side. So basically using Javascript to validate it. If the user for some reason disables Javascript your server site validation would work. What you could try as well would be to post the data asynchronous using Ajax for instance and immidietly return an error message if the validation fails, this approach would be server side.

Answer (score 0):

test this :

`web.php`

```
Route::get('test/', 'TestController@test');
```

`TestController` class :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests\PostRequest;
use App\Post;

class PostController extends Controller
{

    public function test(PostRequest $request)
    {
        dd($request->get('name'));
    }

}
```

`PostRequest` class :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class PostRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        $this->sanitize();
        return [
            'name'=>'required',
            'description'=>'required',
            'description'=>'required',
        ];
    }

    public function sanitize()
    {
        $input = $this->all();



        $input['name'] = $input['name'].'some change';
        $input['description'] = $input['description'].'another change';

        $this->replace($input);
    }
}
```

As you can see, I defined a method called `sanitize` in `PostRequest`

Now when I set the value of the name to the ‍‍`ali` in URL, but the `ali some change` value will be printed.

You can also use the `daylerees / sanitizer` package.

Comment: one additional thing i would do is add isset check in sanitize function. Like:- isset($input['name']) && $input['name'] = $input['name'].'some change';